# Black not respecting extend-exclude in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyproject.toml, python-black

In VSCode, with Python 3.9 and black==22.6.0, I have a project structure like:

```
--- root
------src
---------module0.py
---------module1.py
------tests
---------test_folder0
------------test_file0.py
------------test_file1.py
---------test_folder1
---------etc.
```

In `pyproject.toml` I can't get the `extend-exlude` part to actually exclude my test files. I've tried multiple different ways, both for the entire tests folder as well as for the test_whatever.py files but nothing seems to work, even though my various attempts have been validated by https://regex101.com/. The simplest example:

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 200
target-version = ['py39']
include = '\.pyi?$'
extend-exclude = '''.*test_.*'''
```

Either my regex is wrong (or black requires some modifications) or VSCode is ignoring my project's configuration or idk.

Comment: How are you asking VSCode to format your codebase? If you're using the "Format Document" hotkey (<Ctrl-Shift-I> IIRC) then Black will ignore all file collection options like `--extend-exclude` because VSCode will call Black with the filepath given **directly**. If you take a look at the "Output" tab and then run "Format Document", you'll notice this, for example here's what happens when I do this: `./venv/bin/python -m black --safe --diff --quiet ./tests/data/nothing-changed.py`

Comment: Hi @ichard26, I have VSCode set to "Edit: Format on Save" so I'm not actually running "Format Document". And of course "Python > Formatting: Provider" is set to "black".

Comment: ah alright. It's the same underlying issue though with "Format on Save", VSCode passes the file to Black directly an as argument so `--extend-exclude` won't ever affect it. Your only option is to use `--force-exclude` which is like `--extend-exclude` but is always applied. Your only way of formatting a file that's force excluded is to pipe in its contents to `black -` and save STDOUT to the same file.

Comment: Ok so from what I'm understanding then I can't just use `force-exclude` in my `pyproject.toml` and be done with it? I'm not sure if I should create a little script that pipes the content and saves to STDOUT, but this just kind of feels like a shortcoming of black no? Anyway thanks @ichard26, I feel like you should copy your comment as an answer so I can consider this question "resolved".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maintainer of Black here :wave:

OK, so I actually missed a few points in my comments. To address the main question, this is 100% expected behaviour. Your regex is fine.

The thing is that when you ask VSCode to format your file on save, it calls Black passing the filepath to your current file (you just saved) directly. If you open the "Output" tab in the bottom panel and then save a Python file, you'll notice something like this:

```
./venv/bin/python -m black --safe --diff --quiet ./tests/data/nothing-changed.py
```

`--include`, `--exclude`, and `--extend-exclude` only affect files and directories that are *discovered by Black itself.* You might be wondering, huh, Black can look for files to format? Yes, it does when you run `black .` or give Black any other directory. The flipside of this is that these options do nothing to files given as an argument to Black.

If you want to keep Format on Save enabled, your only recourse is to use `--force-exclude` which is similar to `--extend-exclude` but **it's always enforced.** You can either configure `--force-exclude` in `pyproject.toml` or via VSCode's Black arguments setting (preferably for the current workspace only).

The difference between putting it in `pyproject.toml` and configuring VSCode to pass extra options to Black is well, when it's applied. If it's in `pyproject.toml` it will always be enforced, even when you're not using VSCode and instead are using a bash shell or whatever. This can be useful if you're using pre-commit (which passes files to Black directly just like VSCode) or similar, but can be annoying otherwise.

(if you do choose to force exclude project-wide via `pyproject.toml`, you can format force-excluded files by either piping it in or temporarily clearing `--force-exclude` on the CLI, e.g. `black --force-exclude='' file_you_want_to_format_even_though_it_is_force_excluded.py`)

Comment: Thanks for the help and for maintaining Black. I can confirm that with my above `pyproject.toml` snippet but changing `extend-exclude` to `force-exclude`, my project's code gets formatted but my tests remain unformatted, as hoped. (Honestly thought I tried it as soon as you mentioned it but I guess I was doing something different). Thanks again!