# Cannot get Black to ignore a file

Tags: django, python-black

My IDE is VSCode. I have Black 22.8.0 set as Formatting Provider and IDE is set to format the code on save. This is the first time I apply a code formatter.

This is my Django project structure:

```
project
|--- settings.py
```

And this is my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 90
skip-string-normalization = true
extend-exclude = '''(manage.py|settings.py|asgi.py|wsgi.py|urls.py|migrations/*)'''
```

And the partial output of command `black . -v`:

```
manage.py ignored: matches the --extend-exclude regular expression
project\asgi.py ignored: matches the --extend-exclude regular expression
project\wsgi.py ignored: matches the --extend-exclude regular expression
project\settings.py ignored: matches the --extend-exclude regular expression
```

So `settings.py` **is ignored**.

But I have this in my `settings.py` file:

```
try:
   from dotenv import load_dotenv
   load_dotenv
except ImportError:
   pass
```

But if I save this file, it turns into this:

```
try:
    from dotenv import load_dotenv

    load_dotenv
except ImportError:
    pass
```

An extra line is added after `from`. If I disable Black this won't happen, which means Black is formatting this **excluded** file.

This is absolutely not a big deal but if Black is not working here, I'm not sure it works anywhere.

**Edit 1:**
I switched the formatter to `autopep8` for test and this didn't happen so definitely its Black. So again, why Black formats an **excluded** file?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73296261/18155471 it should explain what's wrong and how to fix it (TL;DR use --force-exclude)